# How can I make Eclipse save the state of the project tree when I quit?

Tags: eclipse

When I use Eclipse I use the project tree a lot, and I expand and collapse folders very often. Is there a way to make Eclipse automatically reload the last state of the project tree when I launch it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the best you can do is select 'Link with Editor' and leave a file open in each node you want expanded.

Comment: Is it possible that this only works with one folder at the time, namely the last one that you link?

Comment: No, it should work with an arbitrary number of file/folder combinations. 'Link with Editor' expands the project tree to highlight the file currently active in the editor. By default, when you start Eclipse, it restores the files you were last working with. The active file's node will be expanded. You do still have to activate each additional file to get its node expanded.

Comment: Right, I wasn't activating the files and so Eclipse didn't expand the project tree, now it works. Unfortunately this is not what I was looking for but at least it's close. I wish there was such a feature though.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly that... but Mylyn is very close to it. In Mylyn the state of the package navigator can be controlled via the context of the current task.

"[Mylyn 2.0, Part 2: Automated context management](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-mylyn2/)" from developerWorks explains it all..